# Solving ODE-systems with Matrix exponential is wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Originally I've learned that the solution of a systems of coupled ODE:

$$\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}'(x)\\ \vdots \\{y_n}'(x)\end{array}\right]}_{y'(x)}= 
\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cccc}&a_{1\,1} &\cdots &a_{1\,n}
\\ &\vdots \quad &&\vdots \\
&a_{n\,1}&\cdots&a_{n\,n}\end{array}\right]}_{A}\,
\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}(x)\\ \vdots \\{y_n}(x)\end{array}\right]}_{y(x)}$$

is determined by: $$y(x) = \exp(A\,x)\,C$$ where $C$ is a vector with constants $\left[\begin{array}{cc}C_1\\ \vdots \\C_n\end{array}\right]$ and $\exp(A\,x)$ the matrix exponential, that can be at best calculated by: $$\exp(A\,x) = V^{-1}\,\exp(\Lambda\,x)\,V$$ where $V$ is a vector full of Eigenvectors: $\left[\begin{array}{cc}v_1&\cdots&v_n\end{array}\right]$

and $\Lambda$ a matrix full of Eigenvalues on its main diagonal: $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}\lambda_1&\\ &\ddots\\&&v_n\end{array}\right]$

Now apparently this leads to another solution compared to: $$y(x) = c_1\,v_1\,\exp(\lambda_1\,x)+\cdots+c_n\,v_n\,\exp(\lambda_n\,x)$$

Even if one told me both solutions were to solve a system of ODE

---

For example consider the system:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}'(x) \\ {y_2}'(x)\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 10\\ 8 & 2 \end{array}\right)\,\left(\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}(x) \\ {y_2}(x)\end{array}\right)$$
with Eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 12, \lambda_2 = -6$ and Eigenvectors: $v_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 \\ 8/10\end{array}\right), v_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 \\ -1\end{array}\right)$

According to the second plain solution process I'd obtain:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}(x) \\ {y_2}(x)\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 \\ 8/10\end{array}\right)\,\exp(12\,x)+\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 \\ -1\end{array}\right)\,\exp(-6\,x)$$

However the matrix exponential spits:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}(x) \\ {y_2}(x)\end{array}\right) = C\,\left(\begin{array}{cc} \frac{4\,{\mathrm{e}}^{-6\,x}}{9}+\frac{5\,{\mathrm{e}}^{12\,x}}{9} & \frac{5\,{\mathrm{e}}^{12\,x}}{9}-\frac{5\,{\mathrm{e}}^{-6\,x}}{9}\\ \frac{4\,{\mathrm{e}}^{12\,x}}{9}-\frac{4\,{\mathrm{e}}^{-6\,x}}{9} & \frac{5\,{\mathrm{e}}^{-6\,x}}{9}+\frac{4\,{\mathrm{e}}^{12\,x}}{9} \end{array}\right)\,$$

Probably those two are inconvenient, because the constants are set differently. In fact the second approach is independent of constants somehow. So how's that all in relation with each other?

Comment: Note that it should be $\exp(A\,x) = V^{-1}\,e^{\Lambda x}\,V$. Also it should be $e^{Ax} C$ instead of $C e^{Ax}$.

Comment: Also, your "another solution" is wrong: it should be $y(x) = c_1 v_1\,\exp(\lambda_1\,x)+\cdots+c_nv_n\,\exp(\lambda_n\,x)$.

Comment: Now I read it again: it should be $A = V \Lambda V^{-1}$ (since $AV = V\Lambda$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}'(x) \\ {y_2}'(x)\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 10\\ 8 & 2 \end{array}\right)\,\left(\begin{array}{cc}{y_1}(x) \\ {y_2}(x)\end{array}\right)$$

The eigenvalues are

$$\lambda_1 = 12, ~~\lambda_2 = -6$$

The eigenvectors are

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}, ~~v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

The solution can written as

$$y(x) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 x} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 x} v_2 = c_1 e^{12 x}\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 e^{-6x}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

We can also use the matrix exponential

$$e^{A x} = P e^{Dx} P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & -1 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} e^{12x} &0 \\ 0 & e^{-6x} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 \dfrac{1}{9} & \dfrac{1}{9} \\
 -\dfrac{4}{9} & \dfrac{5}{9} \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
 \dfrac{4 e^{-6 x}}{9}+\dfrac{5 e^{12 x}}{9} & \dfrac{-5}{9} e^{-6 x}+\dfrac{5 e^{12 x}}{9} \\
 \dfrac{-4}{9} e^{-6 x}+\dfrac{4 e^{12 x}}{9} & \dfrac{5 e^{-6 x}}{9}+\dfrac{4 e^{12 x}}{9} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The solution using the matrix exponential is given by

$$y(x) = e^{Ax} c = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 c_1 \left(\dfrac{4 e^{-6 x}}{9}+\dfrac{5 e^{12 x}}{9}\right)+c_2 \left(\dfrac{-5}{9}e^{-6 x}+\dfrac{5 e^{12 x}}{9}\right) \\
 c_1 \left(\dfrac{-4}{9} e^{-6 x}+\dfrac{4 e^{12 x}}{9}\right)+c_2 \left(\dfrac{5 e^{-6 x}}{9}+\dfrac{4 e^{12 x}}{9}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Compare the two results while noting that you can combine constants because they are arbitrary.

Also, if you choose an initial condition, both methods produce exactly the same result.

Comment: Thanks for writing it all out. I feel like I'm almost there of being convinced, if I just would find a way of how to combine the constants. E.g. in the first column I could factor: $(c_1\,\dfrac{4}{9}+c_2\,\dfrac{-5}{9})\,\exp(-6\,x)+(c_1\,\dfrac{5}{9}+c_2\,\dfrac{5}{9})\,\exp(-12\,x)$ What wouldn't equal the first line of the others method. Only by looking at $c_1 = c_2 = 1$

Comment: Try it this way, let $y_1(0) = 1, y_2(0) = 1$ and solve for the constants in each method. What do you get?

Comment: Well, I'll get ... $y_1: \quad 1 = c_1\,\dfrac{4}{9}+\dfrac{5}{9}+c_2 \dfrac{-5}{9}+\dfrac{5}{9} \Rightarrow c_1 = 1$ Likewise for $y_2$ I'll get $1$ ? What is this telling me? If I set to $0$ the other one we have: $1 = c_1\,5-c_2; \quad 1 = 4\,c_1 + c_2$. Doing these calculations quickly I still receive no confirmation, even if I sense the direction in which you want me to go.

Comment: If you finish the calculations in both, you get exactly the same result of $$y_1(x) =  \dfrac{10 e^{12 x}}{9}-\frac{1}{9} e^{-6 x},y_2(x) =  \frac{e^{-6 x}}{9}+\frac{8 e^{12 x}}{9}$$

Comment: Ahh, now I see them, those sneaky little patterns. They were really hidden for my prying eyes! Thank you for highlighting them.

Answer (score 3):

There are two expressions
$$ \tag{1} y(x) = \exp(Ax) C, $$
and
$$ \tag{2} y(x) = c_1 v_1\exp(\lambda _1 x) + \cdots + c_n v_n \exp(\lambda _n x), $$
where $C = \begin{pmatrix} C_1 \\ \vdots \\ C_n\end{pmatrix}$ and we write $c = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{pmatrix}$.

Since we know $\exp(Ax) = V \exp(\Lambda x) V^{-1}$,

\begin{align}
\exp(Ax) C &= V \exp(\Lambda x) V^{-1} C \\
&=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \exp(\lambda_1 x) & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \exp(\lambda_n x) \end{pmatrix} V^{-1}C \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \exp(\lambda_1 x) v_1 & \cdots & \exp(\lambda_n x)v_n\end{pmatrix} V^{-1}C 
\end{align}

since (2) can be written as $ \begin{pmatrix} \exp(\lambda_1 x) v_1 & \cdots & \exp(\lambda_n x)v_n\end{pmatrix} c$, we see that $C$ and $c$ has a simple relation
$$ C = Vc.$$

Comment: Thank you, this specifies the pattern I have been detecting: $c = V^{-1}\,C$